# Place shortcut to application in autostart folder with Install4J

Tags: install4j

I'm using Install4J to build my application.

Is there a way to make Install4J copy (make shortcut to) the created application to the autostart directory in windows?
I know there is a installer variable called sys.startupDir, which should point to the autostart directory, I just don't know how to make an action/script that does what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an "Add startup executable" action in install4j which does what you want. It even works on Mac OS X as well.